# Smallest $n$ in $\lvert{n \choose k} - x \rvert \leq \epsilon$, for a given $x$ and $k=p\times n$

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

I have an orthogonal basis of dimension $d \gg n$, and I want to generate $x$ samples using the smallest subset of that basis with a sparsity level $p$.

How to find the smallest $n$ in $$\left \lvert {n \choose k} - x \right \rvert\leq \epsilon,$$ for a given $x$, a small $\epsilon > 0$, $k= p\times n$, and $0.1 \leq p \leq 0.3$.

If a closed-form solution is not possible, is there any math result that can be used to solve this using on a computer program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doubtful that there is a closed-form. That said, using, say, Stirling's expansion, one has
$$
{n \choose pn}\approx 2^{(1+o(1))H(p)n},
$$
where $H(p)=-p\log_2(p)-(1-p)\log_2(1-p)$ is the binary entropy function. Setting this equal to $x$ tells you that
\begin{equation}
n\approx \frac{\log_2 x}{H(p)},
\end{equation}
so if you need an exact answer, you can search for values of $n$ close to this to simplify the brute force search.

Comment: Could you please point to some reference or proof of the result you are sharing? I tried to use Stirling's approximation for factorials to derive your result but got stuck at ${n \choose pn} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi np(1-p)}(\frac{p}{1-p})^{pn}({1-p})^n}$

Comment: Try this: http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/shagnik/notes/binomials.pdf

Comment: Nice job, thanks! I did a small experimental test and found that for $p=0.2$, the relationship starts to break for $x \leq 10^5$, which roughly corresponds to $n \leq 23$. This is just to point that, as your reference shows, this result has its limitations. For the sake of completeness, I would recommend to add a note about that in your answer. Nonetheless, I will accept it as the answer to my question, it's pretty good!